# Short story in which two biologists are caught by a subterranean predator then rescued by an alien

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this in an anthology borrowed from my local library in (I think) the 1990s. The library doesn't keep records going back that far so I cannot find it that way.

In the story a husband and wife are studying an alien predator. I think they are described as *biologists* but it could be *ecologists* or indeed just *scientists*.

The predator lives underground and catches its prey by sending tentacles upwards, grabbing the prey and pulling it back down into the earth. In the story the scientists watch the predator snare a deer like creature from a herd, and the husband and wife debate whether they should rescue the deer and ultimately decide not to.

The pair have moved too close to the predator and they are also caught, however they are rescued by a vaguely described alien scientist who had been studying the two scientists in the same way the scientists had been studying the predator.

As I recall the story has a vaguely moralising tone about the ethics of rescuing trapped creatures, that is the scientists should have rescued the deer in the same way the alien rescued them. I recall being unconvinced at the time, and I don't remember it as a great story, however it has been nagging me that I cannot identify the story.

Unfortunately I cannot remember any names, or other easily Googled aspects of the story. I think the tentacles of the predator might have been black but I would not swear to this as I may have conflated this with the countless Lovecraftian stories I read involving tentacles. This story was definitely not Lovecraftian and the predator was just an alien creature with no implications of a supernatural origin. I don't remember anything else about the anthology, but I doubt it was an obscure one as my local library  is too small to hold any really obscure books.